# .NET How to get an int comming throught a socket C-Sharp

Tags: c#, c++, .net, sockets

Here is my problem :

I'm used to receive data like int, char* & cie... throught a TCP socket in c/c++, but how to manage that in c#? I will communicate with a c++ server, sending me int, bools and char*. I think my bigger problem come from the fact than a char in c# = 2bytes ...

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my poor english :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I really hope you aren't actually sending a `char*`, as that makes zero sense outside of a given process, and isn't even a well-defined length.

Basically, you need to sit down and write down the encoding rules for all the things you are sending. For example, you might say:

- int is 4 bytes little-endian
- text is utf-8 encoded with a length-prefix (bytes, not characters) as an int
- a bool is a single byte (to avoid boundary issues)
- etc for every data type you need

Then figure out how you are going to partition multiple fields of a single message, and how you are going to frame multiple messages in the same socket.

Or perhaps a better option is to choose one of the many pre-existing serialization formats and *offload the thinking to that*. If you are after efficiency, then "protocol buffers" would be an excellent choice. If you want simplicity maybe JSON.

If you still want to hand-code it, then : start by writing down what exactly it is going to look like on the wire, then *implement that*.

Comment: @Alban heh - I've been helping people with serialization for long enough to know that sometimes people *really do* send pointers (and then look confused when it doesn't work except in their single-process tests)

Comment: Yes it was for saying "suit of char" not a pointer. I know the encoding rules, but since I'm using my socket with a streamReader and a StreamWriter, I'm getting strings, and from this point I don't know how to manage that. But I think i'm just stupid using those stream, using simple stream will be far easier for my case (since I will get byte array, no more strings). But i will have the opposite problem, how to convert a byte[] to a string (each byte will be a 1byte char, since it come from a c++ server)?

Comment: @Alban indeed, I do a lot of io work and I always use a naked Stream (or sometimes Socket). StreamReader/StreamWriter dont help much in cross-platform work.

Comment: (Sorry for your alone comment, I was struggling with my comment, had to delete it many times x) ) --- Ok, but how to convert my suit of 1 byte char to a string in that case ? Is there a way, or I will have to convert char by char ?

Comment: @Alban to convert a byte[] to a string you need to know the encoding. It sounds like you are using ASCII, so: System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes) - although UTF8 will work identically for decoding ASCII data. Note there are overloads for decoding a portion (only) of a buffer - which is more commonly what you need

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! I think it will do the trick! (Yes it will be simple ASCII)

Comment: @Alban very important point: the text data is only ASCII if you are using the first 7 bits (0-127). If you are sending any code-points in the 128-255 range then you need to decide (or at least communicate on the wire) **what codepage you are using**.